# Running perf on a custom kernel that does not come with /tools or gcc

Tags: perf

I need to run some benchmarks on a hypervisor (`Xtratum`) Linux partition.
The kernel version is 3.4.4-xm and comes as an SDK which I only need to path include in the hypervisor makefile.
As noted in the title, no `/tools` or `gcc` are provided for this patched kernel.

Is there any way to get to run `perf` in my Linux partition?

Edit: I should mention that I can add files in the partition. I, for example, tried adding the `/tools/perf` from a 3.4.4 kernel, only to find out that I can't build it because there was no `gcc` either.